# Streaming data from BLE SHIELD Arduino to iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, arduino, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am using RedBear [BLE Shield](http://redbearlab.com/bleshield/) to continuously stream data to iOS.

I'm using chat iOS app provided in the [SDK](https://github.com/RedBearLab/Release/tree/master/BLEShield) to debug the following arduino code:

```
#include <Arduino.h>
#include <SPI.h>
#include "ble.h"

unsigned int reading = 0;

void setup()
{
  SPI.setDataMode(SPI_MODE0);
  SPI.setBitOrder(LSBFIRST);
  SPI.setClockDivider(SPI_CLOCK_DIV16);
  SPI.begin();

  ble_begin();

  Serial.begin(57600);
}

unsigned char buf[16] = {0};
unsigned char len = 0;

void loop()
{

  ble_do_events();

  if(ble_connected()){

      reading = 10; //this is fake data for testing purposes.
      buf[0] = reading;
      reading = reading << 8;
      reading |= 11; //again same fake data
      buf[1] = reading & 0xFF;
      len = 2;
      Serial.print(reading); Serial.print(" -> LSB:"); Serial.print(buf[1], HEX); Serial.print(" MSB:"); Serial.println(buf[0], HEX);

    len = 2;
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
      ble_write(buf[i]);
    ble_write(0x0D);
    len = 0;

    ble_do_events();

    delay(20);
  }
}
```

I'm encountering the following problem: 
the first time I try to connect to the BLE Shield it just executes the loop once and it gets stuck. then, if I disconnect and reconnect, data starts to stream as I would like to.

Anyone has tried this?

Answer (score 0):

I use the BLE Simple to test your program. Yours did get stuck. But if you comment the last ble_do_events() out, everything is fine.

It seems that the app will automatically connect and disconnect from the BLE shield after a certain period of time. I am new to ble and don't really understand this...Is it because when the ble_write is called, the ble will broadcast the app to inform that here is a sms. Then the app will connect the ble and get the sms?